# How do I print only the letters of a list in uppercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python and working on lists.  The items in my lists consists of letters and numbers, and I'm wondering how to print the letters in uppercase.  This is what I have.

```py
dirtbike = ['yz450', 'kx450', 'rmz450', 'ktm450', 'fc450']
message = f"I would love to own a {dirtbike[0]}! As well as a {dirtbike[1]}!"
print(message)
```

I would like the print out to be 'YZ450' & 'KX450' but have only managed to print the whole message in upper using message.upper

Comment: `dirtbike[0].upper()`…?

Comment: I actually did think of that, but thought if I could find a way to print it out in uppercase w/o making the list in uppercase, I would learn a little more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the method upper inside the brackets.

`message = f"I would love to own a {dirtbike[0].upper()}! As well as a {dirtbike[1].upper()}!"`

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).